# How to merge rows into one selecting best data from each row?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, merge

I am trying to make a function that goes through a dataframe, this df has a column, let's call it "matched" which is numerical and it's an identifier for rows that I need to merge, so it looks something like this:

| Id | matched | name | animals | flying | hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | peter | cow | yes | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | pedro |  | no | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | angel | dog | yes | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | joshua | cat | no | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | harry |  | no | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | senna | bird |  | 2 |
| 7 | 4 | maria |  | no | 2 |
| 8 | 4 | juan |  | no | 3 |
| 9 | 4 | luis | lama | yes | 2 |

The most important 2 columns are "matched" and "hierarchy", we are iterating on matched to create the groups in which we want to merge and hierarchy tells us what the best data is.
I would like to have this groups:

| Id | matched | name | animals | flying | hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | peter | cow | yes | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | pedro |  | no | 2 |

| Id | matched | name | animals | flying | hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | angel | dog | yes | 1 |

| Id | matched | name | animals | flying | hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | joshua | cat | no | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | harry |  | no | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | senna | bird |  | 2 |

| Id | matched | name | animals | flying | hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 4 | maria |  | no | 2 |
| 8 | 4 | juan |  | no | 3 |
| 9 | 4 | luis | lama | yes | 2 |

And in the end I would like this outcome for my data:
| Id       | matched  | name     | animals  | flying   | hierarchy|
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1        | 1        | peter    | cow      | yes      | 1        |

| Id | matched | name | animals | flying | hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | angel | dog | yes | 1 |

| Id | matched | name | animals | flying | hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | harry | bird | no | 1 |

| Id | matched | name | animals | flying | hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 4 | maria |  | no | 2 |
| 9 | 4 | luis | lama | yes | 2 |

it should end up all in one df so the outcome really should look like this:

| Id | matched | name | animals | flying | hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | peter | cow | yes | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | angel | dog | yes | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | harry | bird | no | 1 |
| 7 | 4 | maria |  | no | 2 |
| 9 | 4 | luis | lama | yes | 2 |

As you can see, I want one row per "matched" group unless there are 2 rows (or more) that share the best possible hierarchy in that group.
The hierarchy is an int column and the best is 1, then 2 then 3 that is the worst value, this being the worst doesn't mean I want to remove it, but it means it would be better to replace if something better exists for that group, also keeping empty values is not a problem.

I would prefer it if the solution didn't use pandas iterrows() since it is a big dataframe and it would run really slow to go through the links

I tried using loops through the columns but it is way too slow or straight up doesn't work as I expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# is the hierarchy equal to the min per group?
m = df.groupby('matched')['hierarchy'].transform('min').eq(df['hierarchy'])

# keep the matching conditions
out = df[m]
```

output:

```
   Id  matched   name animals flying  hierarchy
0   1        1  peter     cow    yes          1
2   3        2  angel     dog    yes          1
4   5        3  harry     NaN     no          1
6   7        4  maria     NaN     no          2
8   9        4   luis    lama    yes          2
```

Comment: Thanks but the expected output is not what  need, since the match nuber 3 has empty values inside when there are "better" options to fill up with

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a join after using `groupby()`:

```
output = df.merge(df.groupby('matched',as_index=False)['hierarchy'].min(),
                 how='inner',
                 on = ['matched','hierarchy'])
```

Returning:

```
   Id  matched   name animals flying  hierarchy
0   1        1  peter     cow    yes          1
1   3        2  angel     dog    yes          1
2   5        3  harry     NaN     no          1
3   7        4  maria     NaN     no          2
4   9        4   luis    lama    yes          2
```

Comment: Thanks but the expected output is not what  need, since the match nuber 3 has empty values inside when there are "better" options to fill up with